# has_many dependent: destroy is searching for a wrong column name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a class :klass that has_many :otherklass, and it's dependent: :destroy.

However, when I try to destroy a :klass, rails is looking for otherklass.namespace_klass_id = klass.id, and understandably not finding anything.

Is there a way to tell rails explicitly that :otherklass uses .namespace_klass_id as the column on otherklass?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After some more searching, a coworker and I found that the answer is adding:

```
foreign_key: :namespace_klass_id
```

So it looks like:

```
has_many :otherklass, foreign_key: :namespace_klass_id, dependent: :destroy
```